# How to bind microsoft graph result to persona card spfx

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, spfx

I'm retrieving an array of person from Microsoft Graph. This array I would like to show in a panel with a person card on. How can I bind the arrya to the persons card.

For the moment I'm having a function that is doing a foreach on the array and then creating the person card to bind on.

I tried it with array.map function but that didn't work.

[the code file can be found here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1juYbEgLjwpxMsEN7fFUTHdhbuLHhA2gV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by changing the following line of code

```
  json.value.map((item: any) => {
    this.setState({
      Users:json.value,
    });
  });
```